# Create larger plane of cartesian points from a smaller plane with few representative points

Tags: plane, cartesian

I have a plane of cartesian points made up of a few points. I would like to use this small number of points to create a larger plane of points similar geometrically to the smaller plane. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Any way to rephrase what you said ? Are you looking for the term "scaling" maybe ? Just multiply all your point coordinates by a constant... Otherwise, I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: Do you mean 'given these points that are all on a plane, create more points on the same plane'?

Comment: What do you mean by "plane of cartesian points"? Do you just want to sample points randomly from a plane?

Answer (score 0):

1) Take three points that you know are coplanar, and calculate the normal vector to that polygon.

2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity From your normal, you can solve the plane formula and randomly generate other points on the same plane.

(to decide with what distribution to randomly generate the points, you could find the central mean of all points and their standard distribution from it, for example)